meshtastic traceroute --host 1.1.1.1 giving inconsistent results?
Trying to automate some traceroute behavior.  Works on USB ports, but, not consistently on --host IP.
using python 2 on windows 10, ethernet connected ip address 192.168.1.80 and the remote lora meshtastic host is a lilygo T-Beam on 192.168.1.87
Executing:

python -m meshtastic --host 192.168.1.87 --traceroute !1c498944
Connected to radio
Sending traceroute request to !1c498944 on channelIndex:0 (this could take a while)
Route traced:
!1c498944 --> !1c498944

yea it works...
Should I be able to traceroute from a remote meshtastic device?

python -m meshtastic --host 192.168.1.87 --traceroute !06e2718a
Connected to radio
Sending traceroute request to !06e2718a on channelIndex:0 (this could take a while)
Aborting due to: Timed out waiting for traceroute

Running the meshtastic app on android I connect to host 192.168.1.87 and traceroute to !06e2718a with immediate reply of success.
The python app resides here if anyones interested.
https://github.com/StevoKeano/meshtastic/blob/main/README.md?plain=1
